# Variable filter for SQLAlchemy Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm adding a search feature to my application (created using PyQt5) that will allow the user to search an archive table in the database. I've provided applicable fields for the user to choose to match rows with. I'm having some trouble with the query filter use only what was provided by the user, given that the other fields would be empty strings.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 def search_for_order(pierre):
    fields = {'archive.pat.firstname': pierre.search_firstname.text(),
              'archive.pat.lastname': pierre.search_lastname.text(),
              'archive.pat.address': pierre.search_address.text(),
              'archive.pat.phone': pierre.search_phone.text(),
              'archive.compound.compname': pierre.search_compname.text(),
              'archive.compound.compstrength': pierre.search_compstrength.text(),
              'archive.compound.compform': pierre.search_compform.currentText(),
              'archive.doc.lastname': pierre.search_doctor.text(),
              'archive.clinic.clinicname': pierre.search_clinic.text()
             }

    filters = {}

    for field, value in fields.items():
        if value is not '':
            filters[field] = value

     query = session.query(Archive).join(Patient, Prescribers, Clinic, Compound)\
             .filter(and_(field == value for field, value in filters.items())).all()
```

The `fields` dictionary collects the values of all the fields in the search form. Some of them will be blank, resulting in empty strings. `filters` is intended to be a dictionary of the object names and the value to match that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your definition of the expressions within your *and_* conjunction. As of now you're comparing each field with the corresponding value which of course returns false for each comparison.

To properly populate the *and_* conjunction you have to create a list of what sqlalchemy calls *BinaryExpression* objects.

In order to do so I'd change your code like this:

1) First use actual references to your table classes in your definition of *fields*:

```
fields = {
    (Patient, 'firstname'): pierre.search_firstname.text(),
    (Patient, 'lastname'): pierre.search_lastname.text(),
    (Patient, 'address'): pierre.search_address.text(),
    (Patient, 'phone'): pierre.search_phone.text(),
    (Compound, 'compname'): pierre.search_compname.text(),
    (Compound, 'compstrength'): pierre.search_compstrength.text(),
    (Compound, 'compform'): pierre.search_compform.currentText(),
    (Prescribers, 'lastname'): pierre.search_doctor.text(),
    (Clinic, 'clinicname'): pierre.search_clinic.text()
}
```

2) Define *filters* as a list instead of a dictionary:

```
filters = list()
```

3) To populate the filters list explode the tuple of table and fieldname used as key in the *fields* dictionary and add the value to again create tuples but now with three elements. Append each of the newly created tuples to the list of filters:

```
for table_field, value in fields.items():
    table, field = table_field
    if value:
        filters.append((table, field, value))
```

4) Now transform the created list of filter definitions to a list of *BinaryExpression* objects usable by sqlalchemy:

```
binary_expressions = [getattr(table, attribute) == value for table, attribute, value in filters]
```

5) Finally apply the binary expressions to your query, make sure it's presented to the *and_* conjunction in a consumable form:

```
query = session.query(Archive).join(Patient, Prescribers, Clinic, Compound)\
         .filter(and_(*binary_expressions)).all()
```

I'm not able to test that solution within your configuration, but a similar test using my environment was successful.

Comment: Both answers are producing `WHERE false = 1` inside the statement, resulting in an empty list.

Comment: Just kidding, syntax mistake. This seems to work well, but I don't fully understand why.

Comment: Could you specify what part you don't understand? I tried to explain what is happening, yet obviously that was not enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a query object bound to a table in SqlAlquemy - that is, what is returned by `session.query(Archive)` in the code above -, calling some methods on that object will return a new, modified query, where that filter is already applied.

So, my preferred way of combining several `and` filters is to start from the bare query, iterate over the filters to be used, and for each, add a new `.filter` call and reassign the query:

```
query = session.query(Archive).join(Patient, Prescribers, Clinic, Compound)
for field, value in filters.items():
    query = query.filter(field == value)
results = query.all()
```

Using `and_` or `or_` as you intend can also work - in the case of your example, the only thing missing was an `*`. Without an `*` preceeding the generator expression, it is passed as the first (and sole) parameter to `and_`. With a prefixed `*`, all elements in the iterator are unpacked in place, each one passed as an argument:

```
...
.filter(and_(*(field == value for field, value in filters.items()))).all()
```

Comment: This produces a WHERE clause of `false =1`

Comment: I did not wrote about your filters dictionary having to be comprised of real  field objects, picked from the model classes - the other answer deals into this. I supposed you knew it before I wrote this answer.